# Solving by limit definition

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

To show that $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)->(0,0)} \dfrac{5x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=0$
I tried to do this by the limit definition by pluging 0 to l in lim(x,y)->(Xo,Yo) | f(x,y)-l |. Then i got stucked where i couldnt put delta  to get an inequility. Can some one lemme know how to get this inequility?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\left|\frac{5x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le 5|y|$$

Comment: Perhaps $\left|\dfrac{5x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le |5y|$ since $y$ can be negative

Comment: @Henry Yes.  Edited.  Thank you for catching the omission.  +1